# Telnet to smtp server port 25 --> Connect failed

Tags: smtp, email, telnet

I want to send an email via telnet. When I typed to the command prompt

```
telnet 'smtp_servername' 25 the following message appears
Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed
```

Server name and listening port are correct. I have configured an account with these credentials with Mozilla Thunderbird (Secure Authentication: yes and Connection Security: None) and is working fine.

If I do the same test with the pop server is working fine.

```
telnet 'pop_servername' 110
+OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.
```

Any ideas why the smtp server is not answering my telnet connection?

Thanks in advance,

Albert

Comment: You should mark the answer that solved your issue as the correct answer by check-marking it. This will help future visitors of stackoverflow in faster finding the relevant piece of advice to their problem.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a firewall that may block telnet.exe ?
When using security, the tcp port often change from 25 to something else. Can you check that thunderbird didn't automatically changed the port number ?

When you do a telnet on a port, the other can't know it's telnet, until you type something at least (or timeout if you don't type fast enough)

Comment: If you know for a fact that the remote machine is running a SMTP server you probably have a firewall issue.  Note that many ISPs now block port 25 to the outside world unless you're a "business customer", so the block may be outside your control.

Comment: At the end was the firewall blocking. Thanks for the answers, the issue is finished, unfortunately due to the slow process of communication with the system IT department, I was unable to know the answer earlier.

Comment: Please mark this one as the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You sure you did not set up the SMTP server to answer only to 'secure smtp' (port 465, IIRC)? This would explain the closed port 25.

Another hint: perhaps you need to authenticate first (via POP3) in order to have port 25 unblocked for your IP. Can you try telnetting *after* you successfully checked mail?